# How to use -regex in the find command on Linux command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel

The objective is to find and list anything with "messages" and/or "error.log" etc.. in the beginning then list both "messages.1..99" and "error.log.1..99" using regular expressions.

This command works for however, it would require me to make many -or searches, but to simplify, I would like to have multiple in a set within the search. Like for instance:

```
# find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M -name [messages|error.log|secure.log|kern.log...]?[0-9]|[0-9][0-9] ! -iname "*.gz"
```

not

```
# find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M -name "messages?[0-9]" -o -name "messages?[0-9][0-9]"
```

How might I perform this command with regular expressions?

```
# find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M -name "[messages,error.log,kern,secure]?[0-9]" ! -iname "*.gz"
```

My attempt with regex doesn't print anything in standard out:

```
# find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M -regex -name "[messages,error,kern,secure]?[0-9]" ! -iname "*.gz"
```

Comment: That (the not finding anything) will be for two reasons:  a) `[messages,error,kern,secure]` is a weird character class and not what you think it is and b) there's nothing to match the actually found `./` at the beginning of the file names ... and you can't use `-regex -name` like that, either

Comment: regex matches everything, the whole path, you need to match `/var/log/` too.

Comment: As your complex query does not work, reduce the complexity! For example, try `-name messages` instead of `-name "[messages,error,kern,secure]?[0-9]"`. Then you might get the suspicion that you should look up how to use `-regex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M -type f -regextype egrep -regex '.*(messages|error|kern|secure)\.[0-9]+.*' -not -name \*gz
```

Comment: `find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M -regextype egrep -regex '.*(messages|error|kern|secure)(\.log)?\.[[:digit:]]+.*' -not -name '*gz'`